# Updating a custom field on contact object

Tags: apex, trigger

Trying to use two values for Title in Contact Object if the existing value is one of them then need to update the custom field. Able to do it with one value unable to include the other please suggest.

```
trigger ABMU on Contact (before insert, before update) {

    for(Contact con : Trigger.New)
    {
    if (con.title == 'CEO || Principal') 
    {
           con.Type__c= 'Top Officer';
    }

 }   
}
```

Comment: You will help yourself as a developer if you start using indentation in you code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include logic within the string you're comparing. You need to make two comparisons: `con.Title == 'CEO' || con.Title == 'Principal'`.

Comment: +1 This solves the problem; `String.equalsIgnoreCase` would be better.

Comment: [String comparison using `==` is case-insensitive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm)

Comment: Ah never mind then :)

Comment: Thank you David for the suggestion -- This is working perfectly however if I need to use more than 100 values for Title is it possible to use an array or some thing or directly fetch the values from the data base.

Comment: I would store the strings in a Custom Setting or Custom Metadata Type and query them into a Set to compare within the trigger.